# Problem with serial port, can't get the data if screen is not tun beforw

Tags: linux, serial-port, beagleboneblack

I am working with a Beagle Bone serial port. I made a C program to read some data sent by another board; However, something that I cannot understand is happening.

When I run the program it does not work if I don't run the "screen" command first (screen /dev/ttyOX). I would like to know from the experts, what is happening and why I need to run "screen" first. Can you help me with this?

My code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <errno.h>
struct termios SerialPortSettings;
static int configureUART_Port(const char* pDevice);
void main()
{
          int lSerialPort;
          lSerialPort = configureUART_Port("/dev/ttyO4");
          char buf[2]="";
          int bytesRead = 0;
          printf("Attempt to read\r\n");
          bytesRead = read(lSerialPort, buf, 2);
          printf("BytesRead : %d\r\n",bytesRead);
          close(lSerialPort);
}
static int configureUART_Port(const char *pDevice){
    static int lSerialPort = 0;
    lSerialPort = open(pDevice, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if(lSerialPort == -1)
        printf("\n  Error! in Opening ttyO4\n");
    else{
        printf("Port Successfully oppened\r\n");
        tcgetattr(lSerialPort, &SerialPortSettings);
        /*Setea La velocidad Tx/Rx*/
        cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600);
        cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600);
        /*Parity Bit 0 HC-05*/
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        /*Configure 8 bits por byte*/
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= CS8;
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Clears the Mask       */
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
        SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
        SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
        SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN]  = 2;
        /*Wait for data*/
        SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; 
        /*Update configuration*/
        tcsetattr(lSerialPort,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings);
    }
    return lSerialPort;    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you please elaborate a little on what is happening when "it doesn't work" and what you expect to happen?

Comment: I have never heard of ttyOx - shouldn't it say ttySx if you want to open the serial port?

Comment: Sorry I will change the questions title, I am not pretty sure I am new in working with linux, I think that ttyO4 its okay since when I run 'screen /dev/ttyO4' I can see the data send from the other board,  I read that screen keeps running in BG, and after this if I run my programa I can see the data. What I would Like to know is why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: when running `screen`, it enables the *raw mode*. I changed the code of my program to enable it and it works.

Btw, `ttyOx` is a symbolic link to `ttySx`.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on solving the problem yourself. For the sake of others facing a similar problem, would you mind [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/586275/edit) your answer to include an explanation _how_ you had to change your code to accomplish this?